# Validation of String ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I read somewhere that view model properties must be only of strings.
e.g.

```
class PersonViewModel
{
   public string Number {get;set;}
   public string FullName {get;set;}
   public string Birthday {get;set;}
}
```

How can I do validation of this model as easily as using ValidationAttributes 
and ModelState.IsValid method in 'normal' model?

**UPD:**
I use AutoMapper to map ViewModel to this Domain Model:

```
class Person
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string FullName {get;set;}
   public DateTime Birthday {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, thats not true.  With model binding, MVC will take care of it.

Here is a tutorial.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs